# ASP.NET Watermark over page

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, css

Is there a way to create a light see through watermark over an entire web page? One that stays on the screen, even if its scrolled? My thought was to create a .PNG bitmap and use a DIV tag with a style sheet that has my PNG set to the background image, as well as position absolute set. The problem is, I don't think it will scroll as my page scroll. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you are looking for is `position: fixed` in css. Here is a [pretty good rundown](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/menus) you can check out

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background-attachment property. More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_background-attachment.asp)

To have the background image remain whilst the user scrolls, set:

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

If you want it to remain in one place and disappear if the user scrolls (which I guess you don't, but for future info :) ) The 'scroll' is no required, as it's the default setting, but for readability, you can add it.

```
background-attachment:scroll;
```